# Monitor random shutdown

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer

I am repairing a PC and its problem is that it randomly shuts down picture on monitor. Also sometimes the POWER button doesnt work to turn if off so i have to press the button on POWER SUPPLY. It has 2x8GB CORSAIR vengence rgb pro RAMs, WIN10, GeForce RTX Eagle.
HOW IT HAPPENS: 1.when i turn on PC it sometimes doesnt even put any picture on monitor 2. sometimes when i start it it (the monitor) stays alive for 20-30s then goes black again 3. once in a while it is alive for few minutes (can do some work on it) and then goes black again

NOTE: monitor is not the problem because it is connected to another PC and on that one works fine

Comment: What have you tested? Re-seating plugs and IC's? Checking power level and quality (e.g., lack of noise and dropouts)?

Comment: I have swithced GPUs, powersupply, swithced RAMs and also SSD drive.

Comment: I had a similar problem. Uninstalling and reinstalling the display adapter drivers helped.